# How to measure the time of a subprocess containing a delay in Python?

Tags: python, time, subprocess, sleep

I have a process which contains a delay of 2 seconds and I'm trying to measure the time that the delayed process takes to run in a different program. I've tried a lot of different time tools, including time.time(), time.clock(), timeit, resource, os.wait4(), etc. Any way I do it, none of the measurements are accounting for the 2 second delay in the child process (they all return some very small number like 0.00113...). In contrast, when I run the same code around a time delay in the current program (rather than measuring the subprocess), it outputs the correct elapsed time (something like 2.002...). I know for sure that the delay is working correctly in the child process, it's just not being measured correctly. My code looks like the following (this is just one implementation I've tried, using time.time()):

````
import subprocess

now = time.clock()
response = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'oracle.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
response.wait()
then = time.clock()
time_elapsed = then - now
print("time elapsed: ", str(time_elapsed))```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that `time.clock()` doesn't work, the problem is that your subprocess is either not actually taking 2 seconds to run, or is failing to run at all.

Try using `subprocess.check_output()` instead of `subprocess.Popen()` and let us know what that shows.  That way you won't need `response.wait()`, because the waiting and error checking is all handled inside `check_output()`.

Comment: The subprocess has been working exactly as intended, including the delay. When I run it in my terminal, it waits about two seconds for my print statements to output anything (these are in the main file and start after the subprocess has completed, and one of them prints the time elapsed, as measured by time.clock()). This is shown in my code above. The subprocess prints one word to a separate file. Then, in the main program, I read in that word from the file, and all output has returned as intended. I have also tested the subprocess thoroughly and independently and it works fine.